# Which oils are considered flavorless?

Tags: oil, flavor

The cake recipe is calling for a vegetable oil. I have **refined sunflower oil, and refined soyabean oil**.

Do they qualify for flavourless oils? I haven't noticed any taste in any oil by now! Taste buds problem, perhaps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both refined sunflower oil and refined soybean oil are generally considered flavorless.

Also included among these are:

- Canola (rapeseed) oil
- Corn oil
- Peanut oil
- Safflower oil
- Vegetable oil

The most reliable method of course is to taste the oil :). I'm sure you can actually taste the flavor of extra virgin olive oil.

Comment: Generic vegetable oil is most often soybean oil.

Comment: Around here it's usually a blend of corn, soybean and sometimes others.

Comment: My wife hates the flavour of the refined canola oil (most popular oil here in Poland) and I can taste it too, so I would not call that flavuorless. Though, that may be the Polish oil…

Comment: Asian sourced peanut oil has a reasonable strong flavour. Canola oil varies a lot too, some sources of it are quite obvious

Comment: @TFD Peanut oil is made both refined and non-refined. Refined is fairly flavorless (and is good for deep frying). Unrefined has a strong peanut flavor (and isn't so good for frying). Similar to the difference between virgin and refined ("light" or "pure") olive oil.

Comment: I can't get past the smell of Canola oil to taste it, especially for frying. I threw it away, so cannot speak for baking. I thought I was an exception to all of those great recommendations for Canola oil until I found, on another site (unknown to me now), that many other people have the same reaction.

Answer (score 2):

Most refined oils have little to no discernible flavour. It's the unrefined oils (think EVOO or dark sesame oil) that do.

I wouldn't hesitate to use refined sunflower oil or soybean oil in a cake; nor canola, peanut, grapeseed, or safflower. They're all pretty bland.

Really, the best way to know for sure is to taste it.